# Overflow when adding unsigned int with unsigned int

Tags: c, integer-overflow

I am trying to find a solution for this one (codewars cata, 6 kyu):

> Create a function that returns the sum of the two lowest positive
> numbers given an array of minimum 4 positive integers. No floats or
> non-positive integers will be passed. For example, when an array is
> passed like [19, 5, 42, 2, 77], the output should be 7.
> [10, 343445353, 3453445, 3453545353453] should return 3453455.

And i've almost found it. But obviously i have some misunderstanding about types mechanics here. For the test case

> numbers = {2000000000, 2000000000, 2000000000, 2000000000, 2000000000}

I obtain overflow. And this is totally strange for me. I've read that in C int type size depends on compiling system. I have 64bit system, so my int is very large. Moreover, in this task we have only **unsigned** integers, so it seems that 32 bits <-> 4*10^9 could be enough. I've tried to use uint_32t and uint_64t types. Right now i am trying to cast all variables i have and this is not handy way. What else i need to understand to find the solution?

Here is my current code:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
long sum_two_smallest_numbers(size_t n, const int numbers[n]) {
  int current_low1;//suppose first 2 ones are the lowest
  int current_low2;//and current_low1 is reserved for the lowest one

  int delta1;//variables for comparations
  int delta2;
  //every new value in array to be compared with 
  //current_low1 and current_low2.
  //then define - if new values are lesser
  //and if so - find out is new value the lowest
  if (numbers[0] < numbers[1]){
    current_low1 = numbers[0];
    current_low2 = numbers[1];
  } else {
    current_low1 = numbers[1];
    current_low2 = numbers[0];
  }
  int ind;
  for (ind = 2; (unsigned long) ind < n; ind++){
    if ((numbers[ind] < current_low1) && (numbers[ind] < current_low2)){
      delta1 = current_low1 - numbers[ind];
      delta2 = current_low2 - numbers[ind];
      if (delta1 > delta2){
        current_low1 = numbers[ind];
      } else{
        current_low2 = numbers[ind];
      }
    } else if ((numbers[ind] >= current_low1) && (numbers[ind] < current_low2)){
      current_low2 = numbers[ind];
    } else if ((numbers[ind] < current_low1) && (numbers[ind] >= current_low2)){
      current_low1 = numbers[ind];
    }
    }

  return (unsigned long)(current_low1 + current_low2);
}
```

Many thanks for your answers. I've found the solution after reading all your posts and after some pondering...
So, i've used **signed** integers. Because the **int** declaration invoke signed integer by default. Then i've changed the first 4 variable's declarations to **unsigned int**. And now it works! I do not even need anymore to typacast the return sentence to long.

Thanks to you all, especially @Adrian Mole!

Comment: You could use `long long` for the function type and cast the values before adding. If your `long` is 64-bits you still need to cast ***before*** addition to prevent overflow. `return (long)current_low1 + current_low2;`. Your cast is done after the sum has already overflowed.

Comment: *"I have 64bit system, so my int is very large."* - Do you know this or just assume it? `int` is guaranteed to be at least 16 bits, but it's NOT guaranteed to be bigger under any circumstances.

Comment: Just print `sizeof(int)` to be sure. If your `int` is 64-bits, why does the function need to use `long`?

Comment: Try  `int, long, unsigned long` with `unsigned long long`.  Replace `int ind;` with `size_t ind;`

Comment: I am definetly sure that i have ryzen 2600 and windows 10 x64. So, the information that such conditions could not be sufficient is overwhelming for me. Also, i am new in C. Earlier i have been facing only with Python, so i'am spoiled a little...

Comment: 7race, "such conditions could not be sufficient is overwhelming for me. " --> that is how `int` feels with 2000000000 + 2000000000, overwhelmed 

Comment: try `2000000000U` instead and use `auto`

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин This is tagged as C (not C++) ... `auto` won't work.

Comment: but  2000000000U will

Answer (score 2):

I change the types to `uint64_t` and call it.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

uint64_t sum_two_smallest_numbers(size_t n, const uint64_t  numbers[n]) {
  uint64_t  current_low1;//suppose first 2 ones are the lowest
  uint64_t  current_low2;//and current_low1 is reserved for the lowest one

  uint64_t  delta1;//variables for comparations
  uint64_t  delta2;
  //every new value in array to be compared with 
  //current_low1 and current_low2.
  //then define - if new values are lesser
  //and if so - find out is new value the lowest
  if (numbers[0] < numbers[1]){
    current_low1 = numbers[0];
    current_low2 = numbers[1];
  } else {
    current_low1 = numbers[1];
    current_low2 = numbers[0];
  }
  size_t ind;
  for (ind = 2; ind < n; ind++){
    if ((numbers[ind] < current_low1) && (numbers[ind] < current_low2)){
      delta1 = current_low1 - numbers[ind];
      delta2 = current_low2 - numbers[ind];
      if (delta1 > delta2){
        current_low1 = numbers[ind];
      } else{
        current_low2 = numbers[ind];
      }
    } else if ((numbers[ind] >= current_low1) && (numbers[ind] < current_low2)){
      current_low2 = numbers[ind];
    } else if ((numbers[ind] < current_low1) && (numbers[ind] >= current_low2)){
      current_low1 = numbers[ind];
    }
    }

  return (current_low1 + current_low2);
}

#define SIZE 5

int main()
{
    
    uint64_t  balance[SIZE] = {2000000000, 2000000000, 2000000000, 2000000000, 2000000000};

    printf("%" PRIu64, sum_two_smallest_numbers(SIZE, balance));

    return 0;
}
```

It print 4000000000

`printf("%" PRIu64...` and `#include <inttypes.h>` it for printing `uint64_t`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I meant to return `uint64_t` but this is still words for some reason

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `ind` need to be `size_t ` because it index, right, right?

Comment: As you had coded, `uint64_t ind` works when `size_t` is not wider.  Yet with that code, `ind` could be unnecessarily wider.  Best to match types.  As `n` was `size_t`, the index `ind` does not need a wder type and could fail if `ind` was narrower.  Use `size_t` for array indexing and sizing.

Comment: Should you want more robustness: consider what happens when `n < 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't assume, just because your operating system or platform is 64-bits, that your C compiler has a 64-bit `int` type. In fact, many/most such systems (e.g. MSVC on 64-bit Windows) do not.

If your base `int` type is 32-bits, then the sum of two `2000000000` **signed** integers *will* overflow (but **unsigned** should not).

So, declare your `numbers` argument as `const int64_t numbers[n]`; and, similarly, use that `int64_t` type in the declaration of the array in the calling module. You can probably also use `long long int`, as this should also be *at least* 64 bits wide.

You should also change the relevant local `int` variables in the `sum_two_smallest_numbers` function (and that function's return type) to 'explicit' 64-bit (or `long long`) integers.

Comment: Thanks for advice. But you are telling that "unsigned should not". So, how overflow is even possible in my situation?

Comment: Why `int64_t` and not `uint64_t`?

Comment: @7race For 32-bit integers, the maximum value for **signed int** is `2147483647` and the maximum for **unsigned int** is `4294967295`. The latter will allow the addition of two `2000000000` but the former will not.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 The OP's code uses signed integers, so I stuck with those.